# Python read from a newly written file does not work in module

Tags: python, file, subprocess, seek

I'm writing a python module that works on the files of the current directory.
This is the code:

```
import subprocess

filename="tmp_file"

#sends ls output to a temporary file
with open(filename, 'w+') as f:
    subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-p'], stdout=f)
    f.seek(0)
    result = f.read()
```

However result seems to be empty. Why? (If i execute one command at a time in the Python interpreter it works correctly)

Comment: You haven't checked the result of `Popen()`, nor called `communicate()` on it.  So I think you never capture any output from `ls`.

Comment: Yes, communicate() fixes it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to let the subprocess finish, via `wait()`, `check_call()`, or one of the other alternatives.

```
subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-p'], stdout=f).wait()
```

Also, if your goal is to list the contents of a directory, Python has built-in ways to do that -- no need to use subprocess.